# Accessing multiple arguments in `\newcommand` in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I need a figure like this (four vertically stacked rectangles with text; the two numbers in the texts are different and don't follow a pattern):

[image]

What I did:

```
%working
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\newcommand{\vrect}[2]{ %%% Need to pass an array of 4 arguments
    \foreach \pos [count=\i] in {{(0,-4)},{(0,-3)},{(0,-2)},{(0,-1)}}{
        \node[draw=black,thick,minimum size=1cm] (z\i) at \pos {Val#1#2};
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    %%\vrect{{1,1}, {3,5}, {8,7}, {1,0}}} %% How to use this?
    \vrect{1}{1}
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

I don't really know

- how to pass an array as an argument
- how to access arguments based on the index (tried `#\i` with failure)

Any help is appreciated.
*P.S.* I need to draw few figures like this, so I created a `\newcommand`.

Comment: Is the number of the cells always 4?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes (writing this part as comments must be at least 15 characters).

Comment: So the four arguments are the numbers in the four cells? I'd look at using a `rectangle split` node, no loop will be needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\foreach` command can iterate over multiple parameters, separated by `/`. You can use the array of the loop as parameter for your command.
The position can be set with the counter `\i` by `(0,-\i)`.

Note: You can pass an arbitrary number of parameters inside the array (don't have to be 4).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\newcommand{\vrect}[1]{
    \foreach \x/\y [count=\i] in #1 {
        \node[draw=black,thick,minimum size=1cm] (z\i) at (0,-\i) {Val\x\y};
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \vrect{{1/1, 3/5, 8/7, 1/0}}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can give your array as a single argument to `\vect`, however, it will be easier if instead of using the list `{1,1}, {3,5}, {8,7}, {1,0}` you instead use `1/1, 3/5, 8/7, 1/0`. This way you can loop over your coordinates in the "normal" tikz fashion.

Here's your full (corrected) MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\newcommand{\vrect}[1]{ %%% Need to pass 4 arguments
    \foreach \x/\y [count=\i] in {#1} {
        \node[draw=black,thick,minimum size=1cm] (z\i) at (\x,\y) {Val\x-\y};
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
      \vrect{1/1, 3/5, 8/7, 1/0} %% How to use this!
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Notice that this will work for any number of arguments in the array.

**EDIT**

If you want the boxes stacked vertically this is marginally easier:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\newcommand{\vrect}[1]{ %%% Need to pass 4 arguments
\foreach \x/\y [count=\i] in {#1} {
        \node[draw=black,thick,minimum size=1cm] (z\i) at (0,-\i) {Val\x-\y};
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
      \vrect{1/1, 3/5, 8/7, 1/0} %% How to use this?
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Again, this will accept an arbitrary number of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not tied to that weird syntax:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\newcommand{\vrect}[1]{%
  \def\myarray{{#1}}%
  \foreach \pos [count=\i from 0] in {{(0,-4)},{(0,-3)},{(0,-2)},{(0,-1)}}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\val}{\myarray[\i]}%
    \node[draw=black,thick,minimum size=1cm] (z\i) at \pos {Val\val};
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\vrect{11,35,87,10}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]