# Drawing Grids with different colors

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need a 4*4 grid to fill with selected colors. Basically, I am in search of a `\newcommand`, like this:

```
\newcommand{\mygrid}{11/blue, 32/brown} %coordinates/color is passed
```

which will produce the following grid:

[image].

Similar questions were asked before:

1. [Dynamically filling a grid with TikZ from a data array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315313/38244)
2. [Drawing grids filled with random selected colors and connecting them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208863/38244)
3. [Drawing a multicolored grid using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274219/38244)

I tried to start from answers from all the questions, but got lost midway. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT** This is the last workable version I was trying (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208864/38244)):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{MyRandomColors}{%
    {red}%
    {red!25}%
    {magenta}%
    {magenta!25}%
    {olive}%
    {olive!25}%
    {brown}%
    {brown!10}%
    {violet}%
    {violet!25}%
    {gray}%
    {purple}%
    {yellow}%
    {orange}%
    {orange!25}%
    {cyan}%
    {green}%    
}%

\newcommand*{\GridSize}{4}

\newcommand*{\ColorCells}{%
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\GridSize} {
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\GridSize} {
            \pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomColor}{MyRandomColors} 
            \node [fill=\RandomColor, fill opacity=0.4, draw=none, thick, minimum size=1cm] 
                at (\x-.5,\y-.5)
                {\x\y};
        }%
    }%
}%

%%%%%


%\listfiles
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

    \begin{scope}[thick,]
        \ColorCells
        \draw (0, 0) grid (\GridSize, \GridSize);
        \coordinate (input);
    \end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2** Here's another (based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/390398/38244)) [argument 2 supports placing of grids to a preferred location]:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds,shadings,calc,patterns, decorations.pathreplacing, fit, arrows}
\newcommand{\vrect}[3]{

%   \foreach \mark/\colorname [count=\k] in {#3}{
%       \ifnum\mark=34 \def\mycolorname{\colorname}\fi
%   }

    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}{
        \foreach \y in {1,...,4} {
            \foreach \px\py in {#2}{
            \node[draw=gray, fill=red!30,thick, minimum size=1cm,  anchor=mid,
            ] (z#1\x\y\px\py) at ($(\y,-\x)+(\px,\py)$) {#1\x\y\px\py}; %
        }
    }
    }
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \vrect{0}{6/6}{12/red,11/green}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us what you had when you got lost.

Comment: To the down-voter: please some comments so that I can improve my question. I tried many things, it's impossible to show anything in particular.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Well, I started from the 2nd answer of the first linked question. Modified the `BITARRAY`. Tried to get the values from the method I just learnt (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/390398/38244). Tried to change the fill color in many ways..... Then, tried the first answer in many angles I could try with my little knowledge.... Switched to answer to the 2nd linked question, tried many things... Do you want me to paste some of the non-working codes?

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay It's over five hours now... I lost count what/how many tweaks I tried.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Added one example :-)

Comment: Similar (possible duplicate) to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157080/can-tikz-create-pixel-art-images

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Personally, I don't think it's a duplicate (although very much alike). In this case, OP creates an entire matrix of colors (as in another linked question). My question asks the minimal input (not the entire matrix) for colors.

Comment: You desired syntax, `\newcommand{\mygrid}{11/blue, 32/brown}`, assumes the grid always has less than 10 rows and columns.  Just sayin'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is based on the first edit. Note: I assigned the name `name` to the grid so that you can use coordinates `(name.south east)` etc.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\GridSize}{4}

\newcommand*{\ColorCells}[1]{% #1 = list of x/y/color
  \foreach \x/\y/\color in {#1} {
    \node [fill=\color, draw=none, thick, minimum size=1cm] 
      at (\x-.5,\GridSize+0.5-\y) {};
    }%
}%

%%%%%


%\listfiles
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

    \begin{scope}[thick,local bounding box=name]
        \ColorCells{1/1/blue, 2/3/red, 3/2/green, 4/4/yellow}
        \draw (0, 0) grid (\GridSize, \GridSize);
    \end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Great! Is there any way to specify the location? I need to draw multiple such images in one document.

Comment: OK. Found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144452/38244

Comment: Yup, [shift=(coordinate)] is the key.  BTW, I moved 1/1 to the upper left.

Comment: This is broken on my system. Was working perfectly well until recently. Is it just me? I've suggested an edit, closely based on the previous code.

Comment: @PatrickT the problem seems to be specific to the use of `\color` in `\foreach`, choosing an alternate macro name seems to be sufficient.

Comment: @DaiBowen, interesting! thanks for the feedback.

Comment: This is great, but there are small little white pixels in all the corners (e.g. top left most pixel). How to rid of them?

Comment: actually, it's quite visible to me even on this website. Here is a screenshot of what I mean: https://i.imgur.com/heipcAX.jpg Are you absolutely sure your image viewer/pdf viewer doesn't show them? I tried a couple on the exact image of your post, and they all do.

Comment: No idea what causes it, but you can cover it with `\draw (name.south west) rectangle (name.north east);`

Answer (score 7):

`\definegrid[rows,cols]` defines `\grows` and `\gcols` and proceeds to define all the cells of the grid `\grid[i,j]` where `i` and `j` are row and column indices as `\wh` (white).  Note that `\grid[i,j]` is defined with `\csname` since `i` and `j` are catcode 12.

Then, `\setgrid[i,j]{color}` is used to redefine the cell `\grid[i,j]` to the desired color.

Finally, `\drawgrid` regurgitates the `\grid[i,j]` cells in the form of a stack.

Each cell is an `\fbox`, by the way, dimensions can be set as needed.

Revised for `standalone`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine,pgffor}
\def\block#1{\kern-\fboxrule\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\color{#1}\rule{1ex}{1ex}}}
\def\wh{\block{white}}
\setstackgap{S}{-\fboxrule}
\setstackEOL{\\}

\makeatletter
\def\definegrid[#1,#2]{%
  \def\grows{#1}%
  \def\gcols{#2}%
  \foreach\i in {1,...,#1}%
  {%
    \foreach\j in {1,...,#2}%
    {%
      \expandafter\gdef\csname grid[\i,\j]\endcsname{\wh}%
    }%
  }%
\ignorespaces}

\newcommand\drawgrid{%
  \def\stackbuild{}%
  \foreach\i in {1,...,\grows}%
  {%
    \ifnum\i=1\else\g@addto@macro\stackbuild{\\}\fi%
    \foreach\j in {1,...,\gcols}%
    {%
      \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\stackbuild\expandafter{%
        \csname grid[\i,\j]\endcsname}%
    }%
  }%
  \kern\fboxrule%
  \expandafter\Shortstack\expandafter{\stackbuild}%
}

\def\setgrid[#1,#2]#3{\expandafter\gdef\csname grid[#1,#2]\endcsname{\block{#3}}%
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\definegrid[4,4]
%
\setgrid[1,1]{blue}
\setgrid[3,2]{red}
\setgrid[4,4]{green}
%
\drawgrid
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here is a version in which `\definegrid[rows,cols]{default-color}` takes a mandatory trailing argument that sets the default color of the grid.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine,pgffor}
\def\block#1{\kern-\fboxrule\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\color{#1}\rule{1ex}{1ex}}}
\setstackgap{S}{-\fboxrule}
\setstackEOL{\\}

\makeatletter
\def\definegrid[#1,#2]#3{%
  \def\grows{#1}%
  \def\gcols{#2}%
  \foreach\i in {1,...,#1}%
  {%
    \foreach\j in {1,...,#2}%
    {%
      \expandafter\gdef\csname grid[\i,\j]\endcsname{\block{#3}}%
    }%
  }%
\ignorespaces}

\newcommand\drawgrid{%
  \def\stackbuild{}%
  \foreach\i in {1,...,\grows}%
  {%
    \ifnum\i=1\else\g@addto@macro\stackbuild{\\}\fi%
    \foreach\j in {1,...,\gcols}%
    {%
      \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\stackbuild\expandafter{%
        \csname grid[\i,\j]\endcsname}%
    }%
  }%
  \kern\fboxrule%
  \expandafter\Shortstack\expandafter{\stackbuild}%
}

\def\setgrid[#1,#2]#3{\expandafter\gdef\csname grid[#1,#2]\endcsname{\block{#3}}%
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\definegrid[4,4]{yellow}
%
\setgrid[1,1]{blue}
\setgrid[3,2]{red}
\setgrid[4,4]{green}
%
\drawgrid
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks... When I put it under `standalone` class, I get a white region at left. Is there any fix to this?

Comment: @pushpen.paul Those are added from each line-end.  I have revised to add `\ignorespaces` to the end of each of my macros, so you don't need to manually add `%` to the end of each line.